# How do I deploy a GWT website without Google App Engine? Is it possible to use GitHub Pages?

Tags: web, gwt, github-pages

## The Issue

Hi, I made a GWT (Google Web Toolkit) website, but now that I am done, I'm not sure how to host the website.

The code is only client-side, so I'm not sure where the problem is.

I would be grateful for any advice on where and how to host a GWT website.

Here's the GWT app on GitHub: https://github.com/aryanka15/GWTCledgeTextParser
My attempt to use GitHub Pages: https://github.com/aryanka15/aryanka15.github.io

## What I tried:

I tried using GitHub Pages, but it doesn't work, for some reason the JS file is not recognized by browsers or something like that.

The build Java with Ant Github Action doesn't work either.

I also tried using Google App Engine, but it is a very complicated process that I couldn't get working, and I would like to avoid it if possible.

Also, I used VSCode to develop the application, if that helps. I think that many of the Google App Engine plugins for IDE's like Eclipse are deprecated, but let me know if I'm wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I wasn't being very smart. I just had to change the html to index.html, make necessary adjustments in the js files, and added all the files inside war to GitHub with the same file structure.